# How to avoid Invalid postback or callback argument error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have master page and user control in a page. There is listview in page. I am trying to use itemcommand but it raise error - Invalid postback or callback argument.
(When i remove user control it start working)

```
                      <asp:ListView ID="lvProducts" runat="server"                                        OnItemDataBound="lvProducts_ItemDataBound"                    OnItemCommand="lvProducts_ItemCommand">;
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href='<%# Eval("URL") %>'>
                            <div class="product-grid">
                                <div class="more-product"><span> </span></div>
                                <div class="product-img b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox">

                                    <img src='<%# Eval("ImageURL") %>' class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                    <div class="b-wrapper">
                                        <h4 class="b-animate b-from-left  b-delay03">
                                            <a href='<%# Eval("URL") %>'> + </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="product-info simpleCart_shelfItem">
                                    <div class="product-info-cust prt_name">

                                        <h4><%# Eval("Heading") %></h4>

                                        <span class="item_price"><%# Eval("OfferPrice") %> </span>
                                        <div class="ofr">

                                            <p class="pric1"><del><%# Eval("MRP") %></del></p>

                                        </div>


                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server" CssClass="item_quantity" TextMode="Number" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnAddToCart" runat="server"   Text="+" CssClass="item_add items" CommandName="AddToCart" />
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="a" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Write your code in your question